# How to specify notebook's Saveable option from command line?

Tags: notebooks, command-line, configuration, unix

I've tried various ways to specify a notebook's `Saveable` option, all unsuccessful.

For example, using an external editor, I edited `test.nb`'s source code to change the expression

```
Saveable->False,
```

...to

```
Saveable->Module[
  {value = Environment["SAVEABLE"]},
  If[value === $Failed, False, ToExpression[value]]
],
```

...and then ran the following from the command line:

```
SAVEABLE=True mathematica &
```

The notebook did come up, but so did the Messages window, with the following error:

> The specified setting for the option Saveable cannot be used.

(Putting an `Evaluate` around the `Module` expression made no difference.)

---

Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in an **initialization cell** in your notebook.

```
Module[{val, update},
  update = If[BooleanQ[val = ToExpression[Environment["SAVEABLE"]]], val, False];
  CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Saveable] = update]
```